# What's the meaning of the sentence "or so he would have us believe"?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

> He wrote: 'Pytheas tells us that Thule is one day's sail from the congealed sea... and this Pytheas saw with his own eyes - **or so he would have us believe.**

Mainly the mood or the conjunction bewildered me.

Comment: You have some typos in the sentence which make it a bit difficult. Is 'dail form' meant to be 'sail from'?

Comment: sorry for that -_-

Answer (score 2):

I love AMERICAN English!

"-/, or so he/she/they would have us/you believe." implies that the precedent may be being presented a falsehood, lie, or misrepresentation.

In your example, it implies that Pytheas may be bearing false witness and was in fact, not an eyewitness to the event(s).

Example: "Monsanto is a lovely corporation that makes safe products, or so they would have you believe." implies Monsanto is (or may be) in fact, not a lovely corporation AND/OR does not make safe products. This could indicate direct mirepresentation by Monsanto, or by third parties ('they') such as new outlets or attorneys.

Comment: 1. I don't understand your comment about American English. Is this an Americanism? 2. Is the political commentary necessary to the answer?

Comment: What confused me most is how the sentence conveys such meaning. Could you dissect it?

Comment: Yes, I can dissect it. "-/, or so they would have you believe" indicates and either/or situation. Either the preceding statement/information IS true/complete OR 'they' would have (wish for) you believe something is factual or complete when it is not.

Comment: @IanMacDonald I'm British and "or so he would have us believe" with the meaning as described sounds perfectly normal to me.